# Crontab creation failure Magento 2

Tags: magento2, cron, crontab

I am running Magento 2 on MAMP using PHP 5.6.10 and following this tutorial to create the crontab.

[Magento 2 Setup with Crons](http://claudiucreanga.me/magento/magento2-setup-with-mamp-including-crons.html)

When I type sudo crontab -u Phil -e and enter the following...

```
*/1 * * * * /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/bin/php -c /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/conf/php.ini /Users/Phil/sites/magento/bin/magento cron:run >> /Users/Phil/sites/magento/var/log/setup.cron.log&
*/1 * * * * /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/bin/php -c /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/conf/php.ini /Users/Phil/sites/magento/update/cron.php >> /Users/Phil/sites/magento/var/log/setup.cron.log&
*/1 * * * * /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/bin/php -c /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/conf/php.ini /Users/Phil/sites/magento/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /Users/Phil/sites/magento/var/log/setup.cron.log&
```

I get an error `Pattern not found 1 * * * *`

Any ideas on setting this up ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter what directory you're in while creating crontab entries. Simply run:

```
crontab -e
```

Then switch to insert mode by typing:

```
i
```

Now you can paste in the following:

```
* * * * * /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/bin/php -c /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/conf/php.ini /Users/Phil/sites/magento/bin/magento cron:run >> /Users/Phil/sites/magento/var/log/setup.cron.log&
* * * * * /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/bin/php -c /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/conf/php.ini /Users/Phil/sites/magento/update/cron.php >> /Users/Phil/sites/magento/var/log/setup.cron.log&
* * * * * /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/bin/php -c /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/conf/php.ini /Users/Phil/sites/magento/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /Users/Phil/sites/magento/var/log/setup.cron.log&
```

Now tap on "Esc" key and confirm to exit insert mode. And save the changes by typing

```
:wq
```

You will get confirmation:

> crontab: installing new crontab

Subsequently, you can verify existing crontab by running:

```
crontab -l
```

Answer's rationale: `*/1 * * * *` isn't really valid crontab granularity. You want to run it every minute, which is `* * * * *`.

Comment: Thank you!

Can you help me do this properly....what code shall I use to create CRONTAB and what directory should I be in ?

Comment: Please see updated answer. Hope this helps.